# Manually create / insert data to Cassandra Docker

Tags: backup, docker

I am using Cassandra with Docker. The point is I have an external keyspace definition (with its own proper tables and data storage there) in other host and I wanted to import data from that host's Cassandra into my docker Cassandra one.

- Host Cassandra version is: [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec
  3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
- My Docker Cassandra version is: [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.3 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]

So because I think this is not a compatibility issue, I followed these steps:

1. Exported keyspace definition using

   ```
   cqlsh -e 'describe mykeyspac' > mykeyspace.cql
   ```
2. Went to external host and then created a snapshot of the keyspace data using:

   ```
   scp myuser@host:/var/lib/cassandra/data/mykeyspace/home/myuserid/docker-data/mykeyspace
   ```

   (don't mind about this code, the point is that I downloaded a full copy of the data to my local computer).
3. Mount this volume into docker cassandra in the `docker-compose.yaml` file
4. Started Docker
5. Connected to Docker using

   ```
   docker exec -it container-id bash
   ```

   and checked that the volume is correctly mounted.
6. Using `cqlsh` created the new keyspace with a , no problem at all.

Then using `cqlsh` checked that keyspace is correctly created and tables and other definitions are there. But doing a simple SELECT query results in 0 rows, but the data is physically there under

```
/var/lib/cassandra/data/mykeyspace
```

inside the Cassandra Docker.
So, what's the problem here?
Can anyone help me?